# How to change font-color for inactive list item?

Tags: jquery, css, knockout.js

The html code looks like this and creates tabs at the top of the screen for navigation to several parts of the program.

```
<ul id="navigationMenuTop" class="nav navbar-nav" data-bind="foreach: getRoutes">
    <li data-bind="css: { active: isActive() }">
        <a data-bind="attr: { href: ... } >
```

Now I need to light one of those tabs up in case a certain part of the program needs a users attention. The check for these attentions gets done every 10 minutes and the tab needs to be highlighted if the check returns true. I have this line for highlighting in the viewmodel in an if statement.

```
$('#navigationMenuTop a[href*="registration"]').parent().css('background-color', '#ff4500');
```

The problem is the tab that changes color is not the active tab and the text color will be gray for being inactive. Just setting it to active will change more than just the text color and that is not an option.

How do I change the text color of an inactive list item?

Comment: How is this check performed exactly? Could you post the relevant code? There's likely a better way than mixing KO with jQuery like this, which is kind of bad practice.

Comment: The check is done by calling an external API that returns true if there is any notification for the user. The external API checks a db that stores the state of messages being sent to external instances like government.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried one more thing and this worked...

```
$('#navigationMenuTop a[href*="registration"]').css('color', '#000000');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I went a bit overboard.. but here it goes.
You can click a row and it's highlighted, rows are being highlighted when they require attention, ... all in knockout, no jquery ..

```js
class Item {
  constructor(id, name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
  }
}

class ViewModel {
  constructor() {
    this.items = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.active = ko.observable(null);
    this.attentions = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.getItems()
      .then(items => {
        this.items(items);
        
        setInterval(() => {
          this.getAttentions()
            .then(items => {
                            this.attentions(items);
            })
        }, 3000);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  async getItems(resolve, reject) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const items = [
        new Item(1, 'foo'), new Item(2, 'bar'), new Item(3, 'this'),
        new Item(4, 'is'), new Item(5, 'tedious')
      ];
      setTimeout(() => resolve(items), 300);
    });
  }

  async getAttentions(resolve, reject) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const items = this.getRandom(this.items(), 2);
      setTimeout(() => resolve(items), 300);
    });
  }

  toggleActive(item) {
    const active = this.active();
    if (active && active === item) this.active(null);
    else this.active(item);
  }

  getRandom(arr, n) {
    var result = new Array(n),
      len = arr.length,
      taken = new Array(len);
    if (n > len)
      throw new RangeError("getRandom: more elements taken than available");
    while (n--) {
      var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
      result[n] = arr[x in taken ? taken[x] : x];
      taken[x] = --len in taken ? taken[len] : len;
    }
    return result;
  }
  
  hasAttention(item) {
    return this.attentions().find(x => x.id === item.id);
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```css
table tbody tr {
  color: #999;
}
table tbody tr.item-active {
  background-color: rgba(1,1,1,.2);
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>!</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach:{ data: $root.items, as: 'item' }">
  <tr data-bind="css: { 'item-active': $root.active() == item }, click: () => $root.toggleActive(item)">
    <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
    <td data-bind="style: {'background-color': $root.hasAttention(item) ? 'red' : 'transparent'}"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```